# How to migrate data from SQL Server to Oracle database 10G?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, oracle10g

I have a problem: I have a SQL Server database, and another in Oracle; these databases have the same structure, DDL, same table, same indexes and so on.

The tables in the Oracle database are empty and I need to migrate just the data stored in SQL Server to the Oracle database.

Is there a tool in SQL Server or in Oracle that will help me do that? Or a someway to do it ?

Can you please help me?

Comment: Why do you want to migrate to an 15 years old Oracle release?

Comment: SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) is an ETL tool that can help with this task. SSIS is an optional component so it may or may not already be installed. If not, run SQL Server setup to add it.

Answer (score 0):

Have a tool in SQL Developer called "Migrate to Oracle" where by it To migrate data from SQL Server to Oracle